# Sequelize converts passed date object to local date

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

When I execute a query that that has a data passed as replacement, the date is not set as UTC-Date in the query.

My code:

```
let startInterval = moment('2020-12-09').toDate();

db.query(`
    SELECT kv.kpiId
    FROM kpiValues kv
    WHERE kv.insertDate >= :startInterval
`, {
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
    replacements: {
        startInterval: startInterval,
    }
}).catch(next)
```

Printing the startInterval variable results in `2020-12-08T23:00:00.000Z`.
When I output the query it shows

```
SELECT kv.kpiId
FROM kpiValues kv
WHERE kv.insertDate >= '2020-12-09 00:00:00.000'
```

The column is a sequelize Date column (SQL Datetime). The value in the query is my local time - but the database should only use UTC values - so I would expect it to use `2020-12-08T23:00:00.000` in the query. What can I do?

The sequelize connection:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUser, dbPassword, {
    host: Settings.dbUrl,
    port: dbPort,
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    dialectOptions: {},
    timezone: '+00:00',
    pool: {
        max: 70,
        min: 5,
        acquire: 30000
    },
    define: {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    },
    logging: true // Remove property when all statements that are executed should be printed
});
```

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: @Anatoly mariaDB

Comment: In MariaDB datetime stored `as is` without timezone information. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/#time-zones

Comment: @Anatoly is there anything that can be done? Does sequelize never handle this in raw SELECT queries? In the sequelize insert and update functions it uses the UTC time automatically

Comment: Can you pass a UTC datetime as a string?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes I can do that - I finally did. But I would call it a workaround, I think sequelize should provide a method to automatically do that for every date that is passed as it is done in the create or update function. This functionality is missing for raw queries.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no solution for this problem with mariaDB as DBMS using sequelize the following workaround works:
Just manually pass the replacement variable as UTC-String:

```
dateVariable.toISOString()
```